# Деструктор для итератора. С++

Tags: c++, итераторы

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема с итераторами.
У меня имеется обычный итератор для древа:

```
class iterator
{
public:
    typedef iterator self_type;
    typedef std::pair<Key, mapped_type> value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef int difference_type;
    pointer currPair;
    //constructors
        iterator()
        {
            curr = nullptr;
            currPair = nullptr;
        }
        iterator(Tree_ &n)
        {
            curr = &n;
            if (curr)
            {
                currPair = new value_type;
                *currPair = std::make_pair(curr->key, curr->getValue());
            }
        }
        iterator(const self_type& other)
        {
            curr = other.curr;
            currPair = new value_type;
            *currPair = *other.currPair;
        }
        iterator(const std::pair<Key, mapped_type>& other)
        {
            curr = other.curr;
            currPair = other.currPair;
        }
    //operators
        //prefix increment
        self_type& operator++() {
        if (currPair && curr)
            if (currPair->second != curr->getValue())
                curr->setValue(currPair->second);
        curr = successor(); // point to next node
        if (curr)
            *currPair = std::make_pair(curr->key, curr->getValue());
        return *this;
    }
        // postfix increment (it++)
        self_type operator++(int)
    {
        self_type old = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return old;
    }
        //reference
        reference operator*() const {
            return *currPair;
        }
        //pointer
        pointer operator->()
        {
            return currPair;
        }
        // Inequality test operator
        bool operator!=(self_type const & other) const {
            return this->curr != other.curr;
        }
        // Dereference operator 
        bool operator==(self_type const & other) const {
            return this->curr == other.curr;
        }
    operator const_iterator() const { return const_iterator(); }

private:        
    Tree_* curr;
    //Successor
    Tree_* successor()
    {
        if (curr)
            if (curr->right != 0) {
                curr = curr->right;
                while (curr->left != 0)
                    curr = curr->left;
            }
            else {
                Tree_* y = curr->parent;
                if (y == nullptr)
                    return nullptr;
                while (curr == y->right) {
                    curr = y;
                    y = y->parent;
                    if (y == nullptr)
                        return nullptr;
                }
                if (curr->right != y)
                    curr = y;
            }
            return curr;
    }
};
```

`currPair` у меня указатель и я в конструкторе аллокую для него место в памети.
На англо форуме прочитал что итератору не нужен деструктор. Но проведя тесты я выявил, что в конструкции:

```
for (auto& i : myMap1) {
            i.second = 0;
        }
```

где myMap1 это дерево, место в памети отданное для currPair остается за ним.

Следовательно нужен деструктор(я не представляю какой, ведь тестовая конструкция это пример стандартного использования итератора с древом)..

Или нужно изменить систему работы итратора дабы не было поинтеров. Но для моего задания поинтер необходим.

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как избежать утечки памети?

Comment: Лучший выход (да, возможно здесь это будет, что называется, "из пушки по воробьям", но полезно познакомиться и всегда использовать) "умные указатели". `shared_ptr`, например.

Comment: но чем они помогут при выходе из цикла for `(auto& i : myMap1)` ? инстанции `currPair` для `it`   все еще будут существовать. А если таких форов будет 100000, то утечка будет огромной.

Comment: такие указатели, если грубо, подсчитывают количество ссылок. И когда их не останется - очищается память.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вникал в код Вашего итератора, ибо там много плохо структурированного кода, который читать нет никакого желания, но, я не вижу не одной причины почему `currPair` должен иметь тип `pointer`, сделайте его тип `value_type` и не будет у Вас никакого выделения памяти, следовательно нечего будет освобождать.

А вообще, по уму, итератор это простая структура, в которой не нужно заводить новые сущности, нужно использовать только то, что представляет контейнер, а не создавать непонятно зачем ещё один объект с [ключ, значение]

Comment: Условие задания было таково, создать контейнер похожий по функционалу на map,с <key,value> , но нужно чтобы ключ сохранялся в структуре, а валуе в файле , где ключ = названию файла.Так же итератор должен поддерживать функционал   `for (pm2_t::value_type& it : myMap) {
   it.second = it.second + 1;
  }` Потому мне нужна переменная pair.

Comment: @Demolver, ну бог с ней, пусть будет нужна, но зачем Вам указатель?

Comment: Мне нужно менять значения, скажем при цикле `for (pm2_t::value_type& it : myMap) { it.second = it.second + 1; }` мне нужно в операторе ++ понять что у итератора изменили значение `value`  и сохранить новое значение в файл. Так же по заданию я должен написать итератор так, дабы работал код `int v = (*(it++)).second;`

Comment: @Demolver, это всё замечательно, но я так и не вижу причины использовать указатель, а не простой `value_type`

Comment: Задание такое, что в итераторе должен быть оператор `operator*()` & `operator->()`. Уточню, итератор должен быть is_reference, is_default_constructible,is_convertible.

Comment: @Demolver, ну вот в `operator*()` Вы будете возвращать `currPair`, а в `operator->()` — `&currPair` и по прежнему никакого выделения памяти

Comment: Я уже пробовал, не получается. при попытке вернуть currPair в `operator*()` компилятор ругается `C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'const std::pair<Key,FileType>' to 'std::pair<Key,FileType> '  `

Comment: Решил проблему с возвращением currPair. Но тогда мне не понятно почему в стд map  используются указатели... И как мне определять что например итератор пустой.

Comment: @Demolver, у Вас ещё есть `curr` по которому можно определять, а так — думайте, Вам для того задание и дано. В `std::map::iterator` никто память не выделяет, там всё по умному должно быть сделано.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38815/discussion-between-demolver-and-ixsci).

Answer (score -1):

Выделяя память, Вы не выделяете память для указателя, а создаёте новый элемент типа `value_type`. Память под указатель у Вас выделяется вот здесь:

```
pointer currPair;
```

Она освобождается автоматически вместе с удалением объекта класса `iterator`.

Конструкторы копирующие должны выглядеть так:

```
iterator(Tree_ &n)
{
   curr = &n;
   if (curr)
      currPair = n.root();
   else
      currPair = nullptr;
}
iterator(const self_type& other)
{
    curr = other.curr;
    currPair = other.currPair;
}
```

Comment: Ловите -1, кто будет память очищать, которую выделили под `value_type` и указатель на которую поместили в `currPair`?

Comment: `pointer currPair;` =  `value_type* currPair;` так что я обязан выделить для нее память в конструкторах. А вот как ее очистить не представляю.